# Apache2 Subversion committed files location

Tags: svn, file, apache2, location

Where would I configure or find out where the committed files to the repository is located on the server so that I can view/edit them there?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit the files in the repo. They are not stored in their original form and are not meant to be edited manually. If you have to make changes to the files, do them from a working copy.